# plupload queue checking files on form submit has an issue

Tags: plupload

I'm having an issue in firing the uploader.start() in case if start button is not clicked for file upload, I am using latest version Plupload. here is the complete code, and I want to find the temp names given for each file uploaded on submit click, so that I can go to the server and rename the files with the reference ID which makes easy to identify the file that belongs.

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <link href="Styles/jquery.plupload.queue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/FileUpload/plupload.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/FileUpload/jquery.plupload.queue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
          $("#Testloader").pluploadQueue({
              runtimes: 'flash',
              url: 'FileUpload.ashx',
              max_file_size: '100mb',
              urlstream_upload: true,
              chunk_size: '5MB',
              //unique_names: false,
              multiple_queues: true,

              filters: [
            { title: "Document files", extensions: "pdf,doc,docx,tiff" },
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,png" }
        ],
              // Flash settings
              flash_swf_url: 'Images/plupload.flash.swf',

              //                    // Silverlight settings
              //                    silverlight_xap_url: 'assets/resources/plupload.silverlight.xap',

              init: {
                  FileUploaded: function (up, file, info) {
                  },                 
                  FilesRemoved: function (up, files) {
                      plupload.each(files, function (file) {

                      });
                  }
              }

          });
      });
      $('form').submit(function (e) {
          alert("clicked me");
          var uploader = $("#Testloader").pluploadQueue();
          // Files in queue upload them first
          if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
              // When all files are uploaded submit form
              uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                  if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                      // $('form')[0].submit();
                      alert("Form submitted");
                  }
              });
              uploader.start();

          } else {

              alert('You must queue at least one file.');

          }
          return false;
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Testloader">      
    </div>
   <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, could you explain "temp names" ? (And maybe your whole form process) What you want to achieve is not clear.
In fact, upon form submission, plupload checks if there are still files in the queue. If so, plupload delays form submission until all files have been uploaded. Then it submits the form.

Comment: Temp Names are nothing but Temporary name for the files uploaded. I got this by giving unique names and storing those names in the client side in a hash table and then on submit click sending the array to webmethod and renaming all the uploaded files with the Reference ID. I agree plupload has a check on submit form event, but  this is the place where excatly I am struck with javascript error. uploader.files.length --- line says length is undefined...on the submit form event instance of plupload is not happening, if so, length property might be having an issue.. pls point on the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should move the submit binding inside the $(document).ready to ensure the DOM is ready for submit binding.

I guess you should try relying on a closure to ensure "uploader" is correctly bound during StateChanged (you could also begin your StateChanged Handler with var uploader = $("#Testloader").pluploadQueue();) :

```
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
      alert("clicked me");
      var uploader = $("#Testloader").pluploadQueue();
      // Files in queue upload them first
      if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
          // When all files are uploaded submit form
          uploader.bind('StateChanged', (function(closedUploader){return function () {
              if (closedUploader.files.length === (closedUploader.total.uploaded + closedUploader.total.failed)) {
                  // $('form')[0].submit();
                  alert("Form submitted");
              }
          };})(uploader)
          );
          uploader.start();

      } else {

          alert('You must queue at least one file.');

      }
      return false;
  });
```

Hope this will help